# JsonB GIN index is not being used when queried with OR

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, indexing

I have an `activity` table which has a column called `sources` which is `jsonB`. It looks something like this:

```
{"sfEventId": "exampleSfEventId", "eventId":"exampleEventId"}}
```

I have a simple GIN index on this column

```
CREATE INDEX "activitysources" ON "public"."activity" USING "gin" ("sources");
```

### Now when I query this table using the query below, the index is not being hit. It does a sequence scan.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT
id
FROM "activity"
WHERE (("sources" @> '{"sfEventId":"exampleSfEventId"}') OR ("sources" @> 
'{"eventId":"exampleEventId"}'))
LIMIT 1
```

### Query plan of the above query:
[image]

However, If I remove the `OR` and do either one of the query, the index is being hit.

---

```
EXPLAIN SELECT
id
FROM "activity"
WHERE (("sources" @> '{"sfEventId":"exampleSfEventId"}'))
LIMIT 1
```

### Query Plan of the above query
[image]

Any ideas how can I make Posgtres use the index even when using `OR`?

Comment: Could you please share the results from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS), in plain text, for this query? And how many records does your table have? It looks like there are just a few records, that could be the reason why the planner picks the sequential scan

Comment: Try `"sources" @@ '$.sfEventId == "exampleSfEventId" || $.eventId == "exampleEventId"';`

Comment: It uses the seq scan because it thinks it will be faster--which for all we know that is true.  Note that the estimated cost are already similar, and if you were to double the bitmap index scan cost with an OR it would then be more expensive.